# Spawn multiple services from same service class in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, service, notifications

I am trying to build a chat app. I am using Firebase Realtime Database to store my users and messages. Each user has multiple chats. Each chat has a unique chat id. I need to listen to the chats in background and send notifications when a new nessage is added. There are multiple chats, and each needs to be listened to. I want to use services to do this, but I can't figure out how I would go about doing it.

There are separate documents for users and chats. The user document has a child for each user with an unique userid. Each user has a child called 'chats', where an unique chatid is stored as the key, with the value being the userid of the reciever of that chat.
The chat document has chats with unique chatid. Each chatid has multiple messages with unique messageid. Every message has a creationtime, a message and the id of the sender.

The Database Schema is the following:

```
users
|-- userid1
|   |-- chats
|   |   |-- chatId1 : userid2
|   |   |-- chatId2 : userid3
|   |-- name : user title
|   |-- number : user phone number
|
|-- userid2
|   |-- chats
|   |   |-- chatId1 : userid1
|   |   |-- chatId3 : userid3
|   |-- name : user title
|   |-- number : user phone number



chat
|-- chatid1
|   |-- messageid1
|   |   |-- createAt : creation time
|   |   |-- message : message
|   |   |-- senderID : id of the sender
|   |
|   |-- messageid1
|   |   |-- createAt : creation time
|   |   |-- message : message
|   |   |-- senderID : id of the sender
|
|-- chatid2
|   |-- messageid1
|   |   |-- createAt : creation time
|   |   |-- message : message
|   |   |-- senderID : id of the sender
```

I would like to attach a child event listener to each chatid. They must all listen in parallel and when a child is added to any chatid I need to send a notification. Do I spawn multiple services? If yes, then how do I do that? From what I have read of services, calling startService doesn't spawn a new service. If that is the wrong approach, then what other option is there?

Comment: You don't want multiple `Services`. You want multiple listeners. Probably something like [ValueEventListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ValueEventListener).

Comment: If you consider at some point in time to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), here you can find a tutorial on how to create a complete and functional [Firestore Chat App](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb).

Comment: @greeble31 So you suggest adding a listener for each chat?

Comment: @AlexMamo I'm already far too deeply committed in realtime database to switch now. From what I understand Firestore really would'nt be that different. Thanks for the link though.